# Syncing problem while interacting with multiple nodes

Tags: go-ethereum

I have private network running on two nodes. First node is aws instance and second is on my own computer with graphics card. Second node is much more powerful. When I create contract on first node(aws instance) and send few transactions to this contract, it is mined quite quickly. But when I connect the second node, it overtake the first one and I am unable to confirm any transaction with the first node. When I add second node, I cannot even get data from the contract.

How can I relay transactions received by the first node ( which are not included because first node is not fast enough )?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was with the price of the gas. Transactions did not have it specified, so it was probably zero. When I included gasprice in the transaction, it started to work.

T